# ListItem view change

Tags: android, listview, onclick, listitem

I have a [horizontal listview](https://github.com/inazaruk/android-dev-smart-lib) and custom adapter for it. OnItemClickListener is applied to each item and works fine. Now i would like to enlarge an item when it's clicked. OnItemClicked method is posted below but it does not work. Does anybody know how to achieve this?

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

        arg1.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(arg1.getMeasuredWidth() * 2, arg1.getMeasuredHeight() * 2));
        arg1.requestLayout();
        mListView.invalidate();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use an ExpandableListView ?

Take a look at those open sources library maybe some can help you :
http://www.androidviews.net/

Comment: I need it horizontally oriented (ExpandableListView does not support horizontal orientation as far as i know). Basically I would just like to change a layout of a clicked item. But thanks for the link! Very useful stuff!

Comment: @codeMagic At least i'm trying to help him. Instead of criticizing me you should post some solution... ok my question should be a comment, and your comment is pretty usefull thanks you made my day

Comment: Easy fella, it happens. When someone sees something that should be changed in a post then we make suggestions so everyone can learn how to use the site better and make it more productive for all of us. I wasn't trying to be a jerk with my comment...it was just constructive criticism

Comment: @marmelade i've googled and didn't find the miracle solution... Did you try something like that view.setlayoutparams(new Listview.setlayoutparams(widht, height)); ? If it shows an error before do "new LinerLayout.setLayoutparams...." compile then new Listview.setlayoutparams

Comment: Thx for help! @Yume117 as you can see I have tried with .setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout...), because root element of my listitem view is relative layout. No success though but I think i know why. When I call .invalidate() on listview, listitems are redrawn and they get their layout with getView() method which returns default layout (not enlarged), that's why no changes appear. So probably I will have to modify getView method in a way that it will return modified layout for clicked item and default layout for others.

Comment: Maybe that could do the trick, if it still doesn't works edit your question with new code. Try to add an animation for the expand

Answer (score -2):

Why not use CSS :focus selector ?

```
#myElement:focus{
  width:100px
}
```

Comment: Uhm... are you sure you're not drunk ?